# how to get x no. columns data from same row to single column with comma seperated

Tags: arrays, csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I want all data from column "A" to single-cell "d5" with comma-separated.

Example:
I have the following data in a sheet.

```
A1=john
A2=berry
A3=spartan
A4=sparrow
```

result i need is `"john,berry,spartan,sparrow"` in cell "d5".

Also, it would be great if I can set the desired no of rows instead of all.
like if required one than = "john" and
if required three than = "john,berry,spartan"

Comment: In excel, copy then paste special with transpose.

Comment: hi, but i want to automatic process

Comment: Then apply what I suggested using vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(","; 1; A:A)
```

[image: 0]

---

for 3 use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(","; 1; A1:A3)
```